# Is there a performance and/or safety issue with creating a task per iteration of a large while loop?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, semaphore

I am querying a database and retrieving hundreds of thousands of records. I then read over the SqlReader returned and create a new task per record. The new task then does some long running operation.

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
    void ProcessRecords(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            return;
        }
        using (reader)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var filePath = BuildFilePath(reader);
                var imageId = (int)reader["PhotoID"];
                Task.Run(() => { ProcessRecord(imageId, filePath); })
                    .ContinueWith((task) => { Progress.Report("Processing " + Path.GetFileName(filePath)); });
            }
        }
    }
```

I was advised by a senior developer to use a semaphore to limit the number of threads used by tasks. Is this the right way to approach this?

Comment: With the code you showed, `ProcessRecords` can return before processing of all records is completed. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes it is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is always,

**How much overhead does parallelism require, for unit work done by the parallelism?**

That depends on the overhead for managing parallelism, and the amount of work done.

In general, cheap parallelism requires tens to hundreds of instructions to fork a parallel unit of work.   This means the work to do must be thousands of instructions to allow the parallelism overhead to be dominated by the actual work being done.

Done clumsily (e.g., "create a thread") the "parallelism" cost is much larger because creating threads is not cheap.   Most computations are not expensive enough to justify the fork done this way.

OP's example may be the really rare case where it might make sense: doing some transaction against the disk, which takes tens of milliseconds if the heads have to move.

In general, doing parallel I/O against a disk drive doesn't work; it only has one head, and thus parallel operations against the disk serialize and don't overlap.

If "ProcessRecord" time dominates the disk time, this code may be effective.  (Surely, OP has measured his program to see how effective it is?).  In this case, limiting the number of live threads to some multiple of the number of CPUs will probably achieve as much parallelism as not limit could do, without burning gigabytes of memory keeping track of tens of thousands of threads (if your OS will even do it) that a long file list might provide.